# I am trying to extract data from a json file and write that data into variables

Tags: swift

I have a json file which I added to my project. The file contains 20 sets of data. The keys for this data are "Code", "Name", "Date", "Main", "Sup" and the data associated with these keys is of type String.

I have read the data to a local variable `myData` and then verified that the data is present by using a print statement to printed the contents of `myData`.

I want to extract the data from `myData` using the keys "Date" and "Main" and combine it into another String variable and I want to be able to do this for each of the 20 data sets.

I have tried using `myData.Date` & `myData.Main`, but the compiler complains and calls me an idiot. I am thinking that I should write the contents of `myData` to an array or dictionary but have been unable to do that, after days of searching the internet for a solution it's time to ask for some help.

`myData` contains data in the following form:

```
[{
    "Code" : "ABC"
    "Name" : "Fred"
    "Date" : "01/10/2019 13:00"
    "Main" : "1,2,3,4,5,6"
    "Sup"  : "Nil"
},
{
    "Code" : "DEF"
    "Name" : "Pete"
    "Date" : "03/10/2019 11:00"
    "Main" : "7,8,9,10,11,12"
    "Sup"  : "Nil"
}]
```

I verified that the json data was present by using:

```
let myData=readJFile(myJasonData)//this puts the json data into myData

print(myData)//this prints the contents of myData to console
```

I have created a data struct

```
struct  JsonData: Codable
{
    var code : String
    var Name : String
    var Date : String
    var Main : String
    var Sup  : String

}//struct lotData
```

and ensured that the keys in the json file match

```
let myDecoder = JSONDecoder()
let arrayDict = try myDecoder.decode(JsonData.self, from: myData)

print(arrayDict.Date)
print(arrayDict.Main)
```

The expected result is

```
variable1 = "01/10/2019 13:00,1,2,3,4,5,6"

variable2 = "03/10/2019 11:00,7,8,9,10,11,12"
```

many thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

Please `catch` and `print` Decoding errors. They tell you exactly what's wrong.

The JSON is clearly an array. Please note the `[]`

```
let result = try myDecoder.decode([JsonData].self, from: myData)
for item in result {
   print(item.Date, item.Main)
}
```